# Using modulo for formatting

Tags: c, for-loop, modulo

I've tried to print the array and have space every nth value, where n is equal to the value of numCoefficient so that it visualize like a 2D array at the end. However, it never prints out the if part of the code.

```
printf("\nCoefficient Array: \n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < (numPopulation * numCoefficient); i++)
    {
        j = i % numCoefficient;
        if (j = 0)
        {
            printf("\n");
            printf("Population %i: ", i);
            printf("%i ", population[i]);

        }

        else {
            printf("%i ", population[i]);
        }
    }
```

Note that the array population[] is the 1D array which holds the value with the size of numPopulation * numCoeeficient, which is both given by the user in the actual code.

Comment: j=0 is an assignment. use ==

Answer (score 0):

Oh crap, I didn't use == instead of =. Huge thanks for Tyler who gave me the answer!